# Multiple apk support for Android TV and Phone

Tags: java, android, apk, android-manifest, android-tv

I have a single application in market which has minSDK version 9, and I have also developed a **Android TV** version of this application **with same package name**, but API levels are overlapping.

So, my question is; **how can I upload 2 different apk's (TV & Phone/Tablet) with same package name?** The APK for the Android TV should be seen only TV's and Nexus Player etc. Other Apk must be seen for only phones and tablets at the same time.

I did read all documentations about multiple APK support but **when I uploaded the APK for Android TV over my currently available app, older version became unavailable(not compatible) for phones and tablets.**

Two different APKs with different package names not acceptable in my case.

**I must have single package name, two different APKs, both must be available for theirs compatible devices.**

In my TV apps manifest, used these features;

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="true" />
```

---

```
<activity
    android:name="com.mydomain.android.ui.ActivityYYY"
    android:icon="@drawable/my_banner"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:logo="@drawable/my_tv_banner"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

My Phone/Tablet app is not using feature, has normal Launcher as you see below

```
<activity
    android:name="com.mydomain.android.ActivityXXX"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

What should I do? What did I miss at this point? I need a clear explanation or a solution.

Comment: Have you switched from 'standard' mode to 'advanced' mode in developer console. If not please check [this](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html) document from developer source.

Comment: @ravidl Thanks, It was on the 'standart' mode, I will try it again on 'advanced' mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is switching advanced mode and and using minSDK version properly.

Your latest APK should have highest minSDK version.

For example, if you have 2 apk for different platforms and their minSDK versions are different, first upload the APK which has lower minSDK version. Then, upload the higher one.

Now I have 3 APKs in production. All are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that version code for both of your apks (TV and mobile/tablet) are not the same. Also let us know, what worked for you (in case you already figured it out).