# Android TV and Mobile application both are same packagename and application name how to upload into Playstore?

Tags: android, television

i have develop one TV application with mobile application.when i have generate sign apk see option for 1)Mobile or 2)Tv ,then how to upload 2 apk with same package name in play store!  i want live application for both mobile and tv how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple apk support for Android TV and Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34392781/multiple-apk-support-for-android-tv-and-phone)